# What is the mechanism of the uncatalysed epoxide opening with alcohols?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethoxylation) page says this:

> Ethoxylation is an industrial process in which ethylene oxide is added to alcohols and phenols to turn it into a surfactant.

How does the reaction proceed?

The answer to the question "[Do epoxide rings react with bases?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27288/)" regarding epoxide rings reacting with bases does not include alcohols, and does not answer my question.

Comment: Does [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27288/do-epoxide-rings-react-with-bases) answer your question?

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Maybe that reaction might be one of the reaction steps. I don't know.

Comment: @Martin So intead of CH3O- of that answer, lp of CH3OH will attack? And Eka gave me a link - http://www.chemstations.com/content/documents/technical_articles/ethox.pdf and it is different.

Comment: The link you provided has does not explain anything about the mechanism and it is about a base catalysed reaction.

Comment: @ringo Thank you for fixing the layout. It is completely unnecessary, to include comments on what was edited (that can be seen in the history). The question should be standalone in any case.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン So am I correct in saying that the only difference is that over here, l.p of alcohol attacks?

Comment: @Larry The alcoholate, because it is deprotonated, has three lone pairs, one of them, the HOMO, will attack in a nucleophilic manner. An alcohol still has two lone pairs, and one of the is the HOMO, which will make the nucleophilic attack. The whole process might be slower, as it is less nucleophilic, but you can assume the mechanism to be almost identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of its special chemical struture Ethyelene oxide (EO) is highly reactive material thus easily participate in chemical reactions which includes polymerization. Mechanism of opening of EO's ring in acidic and alkaline medium is given below

[image]

If you see in both cases a molecule with alcoholic group ($\ce{-OH}$) is formed.If the epoxyethane is in excess, the reaction can continue and could lead to polymerization.

A good example is the reaction between EO and water

[image]

As explained in wikipedia ethoxylation is an industrial process to make surfactant from EO. Surfactants are chemical molecule which contain both hydrophobic groups (their tails) and hydrophilic groups (their heads).

The end result of reaction with EO and alchol is a long chain molecule with these hydrophobic ($\ce{-R}$) and hydrophilic ($\ce{-OH}$) group

[image]

Comment: In the first image, from where did the H+ and OH- come from? Where did they alcohol go.

Comment: It just shows reaction environment H+ from acid (HCl, H2SO4..etc) and OH- from base (NaOH etc) [see this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_reaction)

Comment: Where did the alcohol go?

Comment: @larry See the alcohol reaction here R-OH is the alcohol see this [example](http://faculty.uscupstate.edu/llever/Polymer%20Resources/step3.gif)

Comment: But that has an acid and alcohol. Epoxide and alcohol?

Comment: @Larry I am extremely sorry for that mistake , didnt properly seen the reaction [see this reaction](http://www.mhhe.com/physsci/chemistry/carey/student/olc/ch16reactionsepoxides.html) http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/US20040142177A1/US20040142177A1-20040722-C00007.png

Comment: But how do they react? That was my initial question. I understand that H+ and OH- are required along with alcohol to react with the epoxide.

Comment: @Larry the mechanism for a acid catalyzed epoxide ring opening also requires a nucleophile which will attack the epoxide and opens the ring. the opened epoxide ring then act as a nucleophile and attack other epoxides andor alcohol and form secondary products. [see the first page in the pdf](http://www.chemstations.com/content/documents/technical_articles/ethox.pdf)

Comment: What happened in the 2nd reaction which goes to the left side of that pdf? Did H+ of alcohol shift? Is this mechanism correct or the one provided here- http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27288/do-epoxide-rings-react-with-bases

Comment: @Larry You can find acidic and basic catalyzed ring opening in [this link](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_With_a_Biological_Emphasis/Chapter_08%3A_Nucleophilic_substitution_reactions_I/Section_8.6%3A_Epoxides_as_electrophiles_in_nucleophilic_substitution_reactions). Acidic and Bascic catlalyzed ring opening have different ring opening mechanisms. As of second reaction i have still doubts regarding it and i have to consult with my collegues